# How to restart Spark service in EMR after changing conf settings?

Tags: apache-spark, emr, amazon-emr

I am using EMR-5.9.0 and after changing some configuration files I want to restart the service to see the effect. How can I achieve this?

I tried to find the name of the service using initctl list, as I saw in other answers but no luck...

Comment: Did you find it? I am running in to same issue with hive

Answer (score 18):

Since Spark runs as an application on Hadoop Yarn you can try

```
 sudo stop hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager  
 sudo start hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager
```

If you meant the Spark History Server then you can use

```
 sudo stop spark-history-server  
 sudo start spark-history-server
```

Checking the status of the services can be done using

```
sudo status hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager
sudo status spark-history-server
```

**EDIT:**
As [hadooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3259044/hadooper) suggested, for more recent versions of EMR use

```
sudo systemctl stop/start/status hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager
```

Comment: When I tried to start spark-history-server : I get this error
start: Job failed to start
Any idea?

Comment: For those trying on latest EMR versions, change your command to `sudo systemctl stop hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager `

Answer (score 0):

In the 5.x EMR clusters you can also do:

```
[hadoop@ip-10-0-2-93 conf]$ initctl list | grep yarn
hadoop-yarn-timelineserver start/running, process 10632
hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager start/running, process 10771
hadoop-yarn-proxyserver start/running, process 10508

[hadoop@ip-10-0-2-93 conf]$ sudo stop hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager
hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager stop/waiting

[hadoop@ip-10-0-2-93 conf]$ sudo start hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager
hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager start/running, process 1591

[hadoop@ip-10-0-2-93 conf]$ initctl list | grep yarn
hadoop-yarn-timelineserver start/running, process 10632
hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager start/running, process 1591
hadoop-yarn-proxyserver start/running, process 10508
```