# Unhealthy EMR nodes "local-dirs are bad: /mnt/yarn,/mnt3/yarn"

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-emr

I have a spark EMR cluster with 1 master and 8 Spot nodes. Today all the nodes dead while running a job, and spark-shell is also not assessable afterwards.

Click the 'Unhealthy Nodes' in hadoop console showing errors `2/4 local-dirs are bad: /mnt/yarn,/mnt3/yarn; 1/1 log-dirs are bad: /var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers`

It seems related to the disk space issue in [Why does Hadoop report "Unhealthy Node local-dirs and log-dirs are bad"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131449/why-does-hadoop-report-unhealthy-node-local-dirs-and-log-dirs-are-bad) so I **modified** yarn-site.xml as described

```
<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.enable</name>
   <value>false</value>
</property>
```

and **restart** related services as described in [How to restart Spark service in EMR after changing conf settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46709560/how-to-restart-spark-service-in-emr-after-changing-conf-settings). But the nodes were not back alive.

```
sudo stop hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager  
sudo start hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager 

sudo stop spark-history-server  
sudo start spark-history-server  

sudo status hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager
sudo status spark-history-server
```

AWS Console
[image]

Hadoop Console
[image]

From dead node
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have termination protection on? If it's on the nodes cannot be automatically killed and restarted - see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/UsingEMR_TerminationProtection.html